# OTA update fails, can't mount /data/ partition

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to implement OTA functionality for a msm8998 board running Android 8.1. 
I've generated the OTA file and followed the standard way of doing it,

I've run into two problems, solving either one would solve the issue:

1. OTA size is bigger than /cache, therefore even though recovery can mount /cache, the image cannot fit there. How would I increase the /cache size, and is it a good idea to do so?
2. If I put the OTA zip in /data/ or /sdcard/, I have an error during recovery, seemingly it can't mount it. How would I make /data/ mountable?

...

```
Finding update package...
I:Update location: /data/update.zip
Opening update package...
E:Failed to mount /data: Invalid argument
E:Unable to open '/data/update.zip': No such file or directory
E:failed to map file
W:failed to read uncrypt status: No such file or directory
W:Failed to read /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone28/temp: Invalid argument
W:Failed to read /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone27/temp: Invalid argument
I:current maximum temperature: 44756
I:/data/update.zip
I:0
I:time_total: 0
I:retry: 0
I:temperature_start: 44814
I:temperature_end: 44756
I:temperature_max: 44814
I:
Installation aborted.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to use `RecoverySystem.installPackage(...)` method AND have the OTA file be in `/data/`.

Previously I had tried `RecoverySystem.installPackage(...)` method but with file in `/sdcard/`, and separately by setting `/cache/recovery/command` myself and using `/data/`

When using `RecoverySystem.installPackage(...`) and the file in `/data/`, seems `uncrypt` is run on it before reboot, and that makes the update accessible to the recovery.